# Qual é o processo para pedir a inclusão de uma palavra oficial?

Tags: gramática, vocabulário, neologismos

Sou programador, e há décadas uso,e vejo usado no meio profissional  o verbo "identar" e substantivo "identação" para dizer respeito ao correto espaçamento no princípio de uma linha de programa.

O verbo é usado por cognado do inglês "ident". Pode ser que antes de uma transformação de sentido, o "ident" inglês fosse o mesmo que "endentar" em Português - no entanto "endentar" tem um sentido restrito ao ato mecânico de "criar dentes", e não é culturalmente usado entre profissionais de programação. Inclusive como professor, e tentando seguir as melhores regras de português, sugeri por alguns anos o uso de "endentar", mas culturalmente não é o que é usado - hoje uso mesmo o jargão "identar".

O interessante realmente seria oficializar o verbo "indentar", em uso por milhares de pessoas há dezenas de anos, mesmo que em paralelo fosse adicionado o novo significado a "endentar".

Existe algum órgão oficial da lingua portuguesa onde se possa pleitear expressamente a inclusão de uma nova palavra no vocabulário?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nota que a palavra inglesa leva um n extra: «to i**n**dent».

Posto isto...

## 1. Já está

A palavra «indentar» já existe em português.
Vê a [definição no priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/indentar)¹:

> in·den·tar
> (inglês to indent)
> verbo intransitivo
>
> [Informática, Tipografia]  Inserir determinado espaço entre a margem da página e o início do texto de um parágrafo.
> Confrontar: endentar.

## e 2. O processo é orgânico

Não existe uma autoridade prescritiva; por isso, não existe uma autoridade central a quem apelar.

Quando uma palavra ou expressão é usada alargadamente, ela naturalmente torna-se parte da linguagem e acaba por ser integrada nos dicionários e gramáticas.
Pode ser uma palavra nova ([leiaute](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/leiaute)), pode ser uma corrupção de uma palavra existente ([despoletar](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/959)), pode ser um novo significado de uma palavra existente...

---

¹ "indentar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://priberam.pt/dlpo/indentar [consultado em 02-01-2018].

Comment: Sim, está dicionarizado, palavra que não existe em inglês.